# Upgrade OpenGL from 1.2 to 2 for Nvidia GT218 [GeForce 310]

Tags: centos, nvidia, opengl

To run my application `OpenGL version 2.0` *or higher* is required.

`glxinfo | grep OpenGL` yields:

```
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":1007.0".
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa project: www.mesa3d.org
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa GLX Indirect
OpenGL version string: 1.2 (1.5 Mesa 6.4.1)
OpenGL extensions:
```

`/sbin/lspci -v` yields:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Device 1b0a:9060
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 169
        Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at ce000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at ec00 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at fbe80000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nvidia-169_07, nvidia
```

What I've tried:

Installing NVIDIA-Linux-x86-310.32.run driver (It supports my graphics card).

Any pointers how to upgrade to OpenGL 2.0?

System:
CentOS 5.8 32 bit
`uname -a`:

```
Linux xxxxxxx 2.6.18-348.1.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Jan 22 16:24:03 EST 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Blacklist all the kernel modules mentioned in `lspci -v` other than `nvidia`. Restart and make sure (`lsmod`) that `nvidia` is loaded after you start Xorg.

Comment: Centos 5 stems from 2007. Its graphics stack is even older. Are  you sure you don't want to upgrade to something more recent?

Answer (score 0):

Install the NVIDIA vendor-provided graphics drivers. It's preferable to use the drivers (`kmod-nvidia` package) as provided in the RPM Fusion (non-free) repository, or you can manually install them from the NVIDIA web site (not recommended since if something goes wrong you risk trashing your installation).

Comment: Michael I have already manually installed from NVIDIA website..rebooted etc. I am not able to run `glxinfo`. Throws me `Xlib: extension GLX missing on display ":0:0"`. Thanks for your response..any pointers?

Comment: @Vikram you need to tell Xorg to use the nvidia driver.  Check your xorg config file (create one if needed) and make sure in the `Device` section there is a line `Driver "nvidia"`.